# What was Parzival talking to at the end?

Tags: ready-player-one-2018

At the end of the movie *Ready Player One* (2018), Parzival talks to a digital version of

> Halliday in his childhood bedroom

And he asks:

> What are you?

but isn't given a straight answer. I wasn't expecting the question and don't really understand what he was getting at since:

> we'd already seen plenty of this version of Halliday through his memories earlier in the film.

so the appearance shouldn't be that much of a surprise. I'm hoping I missed a detail from the movie or perhaps something from the book sheds some light on the question.

**What exactly was Parzival questioning and what was the answer?**

Comment: may have to vote to close this under 'future-works' policy: http://fandom.wikia.com/articles/ready-player-one-sequel-will-answer-movies-biggest-question - since there is a sequel book / possible film dealing with that very thing

Comment: This is not something addressed in the book, or even brought up, so this should probably be closed based on our [Future Works Policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based).

Comment: I thought it was a *Transcendence*-like thing where he transferred his consciousness to the Oasis.

Comment: @NKCampbell Do we know that future works will indeed deal with that?  If *The Last Jedi* has taught us anything, it's that future movies (books, etc) might ignore or throw away everything set up in the previous movie.

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach - word of god from the author so at least a decent bet

Comment: @NKCampbell - Oh, I didn't realize a sequel was happening. There's not currently an answer to the question without the use of future works? Bummer.

Comment: @NKCampbell Sweet!  I guess I gotta read the book so's I'll be ready for the sequel then.

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach the sequel is being written currently. It too, does not exist yet. ATM all we have are hopes and promises. :p