# In "Ready Player One", is James Halliday dead?

Tags: ready-player-one-2018

I just watched the movie adaptation of *Ready Player One*.

However, I don't understand something about the ending:

> Is James Halliday really dead?

Comment: There is no indication that he is not dead.

Comment: "I am not an Avatar"

Comment: I figured the Game created that representation in memory of Halliday.

Comment: There is definitely the implication that the Halliday figure is... Something.

Comment: I think his physical body is dead but his mind still lives in the Oasis. But that's just my assumption. There is no clear answer.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184820/what-was-parzival-talking-to-at-the-end?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider how was that title a spoiler? The fact that he's dead is revealed right at the start. The title didn't hint at the possibility of him not being dead after all.

Comment: @SQB 's answer below not only has an informative and interesting answer to this question, it's directly from the creator of the work. I'd say that satisfies the objection of being primarily opinion-based in spades.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens - Isn't policy for questions dependent on future works to be put on hold?

Comment: [relevant meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based)

Comment: @JohnP Yes should be put on hold, I fat fingered it in the review so have VTC as per future works.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - That's ok. I voted to reopen before I remember the meta. :\

Comment: The title is not a spoiler. There is no need to edit it.

Comment: @SQB: *"The title didn't hint at the possibility of him not being dead after all."*   You don't see how asking if someone is dead, especially when it's revealed right at the start that he supposedly *is* dead, brings into question whether he's really dead.  And that that's likely to be an important spoilerish plot point?

Comment: @ThePopMachine if it _is_ a spoiler, it's a spoiler for the sequel. There is no plot twist spoiled, except — maybe — the interpretation of an ambiguous ending. I prefer that very minor spoiler over yet another "is this character dead?"-question.

Comment: @SQB:   "What is James Halliday's status?" ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### We don't know — *yet*

Ernest Cline has said in an interview that what exactly Anorak has become, will be an important part of the sequel to *Ready Player One*.

> The movie makes it clear that the version of Halliday Wade Watts interacts with in his childhood bedroom isn’t alive. But also states that the figure isn’t an avatar. So what is going on? We asked Ernest Cline — writer of the book and co-writer of the screenplay — to explain all.
>
> #### GHOST IN THE MACHINE
>
> Ernest Cline: “It’s a mystery, and I’m so happy about that because I talked to [director] Steven [Spielberg] about my potential plans for a sequel novel, which hopefully might serve as the basis for a sequel film, and that mystery of what is Anorak now that Halliday is dead.
>
> “There are clearly NPCs in the OASIS — non-playable characters that are controlled by the system — but Anorak stands alone and he has autonomy, so it remains a mystery. Some sort of ‘ghost in the machine’ was always my idea.”
>
> #### PLANS FOR ‘READY PLAYER ONE 2’
>
> Cline: “That idea is expanded on in the sequel I’m writing. So it’s still kind of a secret. I made sure to finish a very rough draft before I saw the finished movie because I wanted to have the whole story in my head and didn’t want the movie to influence it.
>
> <sub>[Ernest Cline in an interview with Fandom Wikia](https://fandom.wikia.com/articles/ready-player-one-sequel-will-answer-movies-biggest-question)</sub>

Comment: This was my exact thought after the exchange between Wade and Anarak at the end of the film...

Answer (score 5):

You've touched upon one of the most intriguing sub-elements of the film, here.

James Halliday physically died, yes. But, the film almost hints that he's somehow become a genuine, artificial intelligence program of himself. Maybe he found a way to insert his consciousness into the Oasis?

The film leaves it hanging.

Comment: It could be that he is an uploaded intelligence who chose not to answer the question or it could be the Original simply didn't encode a response to that question.

Comment: @Aaron Gullison That is possible, mate. But, the look he had on his face when he didn't answer Wade's question implies something deeper, I think.